# Custom UIViewController container swapping between two views

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios5

I'd like to reproduce the UIView swapping effect from Apple's [TheElementes sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html) where tapping a button in the UINavBar causes the view below the the Nav to flip around and get replaced with another view.

I'm wondering if this code could be updated to take advantage of custom `UIViewController` containers introduced in iOS 5. Instead of having one `UIViewController` that swaps two `UIViews`, it would have a container `UIViewController` that swaps between two `UIViewControllers` (in my case a normal `UIViewController` and a `UITableViewController`). I imagine that it could involve creating a custom story board segue as well.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

If it is better to just have one ViewController should it be a regular view controller subclass or a UITableViewController subclass? The initial view should be a normal UIView but the second view is supposed to be a UITableView. Which would be easier?